# How to compute the pointing accuracy

Tags: communication-satellite, accuracy

I was wondering if there's an equation or somewhat intuitive way of computing the pointing accuracy of a satellite?
What parameters do I need and how would I go about it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: in pure math terms, if you know the direction the relevant portion of the satellite is pointing, and you know the direction it should be pointing, the law of cosines will tell you the angle between those two directions

Comment: Are you wanting to compute the required pointing accuracy?

Comment: what attitude control systems do you have?

Comment: The satellite is commanded to point in a specific direction (this is a vector). The beam peak is actually found at another location (a second vector). The error is the angle between these vectors. Depending on the polarization, you may also have a "polarization error" (as opposed to a simple spatial error). This may be effected by the satellite motion (or, you could also have "pointing error" from a ground terminal mounted on a moving vehicle, and this would depend on how well the pointing algorithm is able to work [essentially, static vs dynamic pointing]).